# how JSP page set member of class

Tags: java, html, forms, jsp

I am beginner at using JSP and am following a tutorial. I have a basic question. There is a simple class named NameHandler that has only one String field called name.

index.jsp looks like this:

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Entry Form</h1>
        <form name="Name Input Form" action="response.jsp">
            Enter name
            <input type="text" name="name"/>        
            <input type="submit" value="OK"  />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

and response.jsp looks like this:

```html
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body><jsp:useBean id="mybean" scope="session" class="org.mypackage.hello.NameHandler" />
        <jsp:setProperty name= "mybean" property= "name"/> 
        <h1>Hello, <jsp:getProperty name="mybean" property="name" />!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

My question is this: I tried to understand how this sets the name member in NameHandler class when the user enters a string.     here what does name ="name" mean? I tried to understand how this sets the name member of the class. The code works correctly, so where and how does this set the name member of the class?

I also know that I can use the name of the bean and call a class function like <%=beanname.classfunction %>. So which one is better? First way or second way? What are the differences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag `<jsp:setProperty name= "mybean" property= "name"/>` works as the following. First it finds bean named `mybean`. The it takes value of `property` attribute (`name` in your case), capitalizes it and prepends `set`, and constructs method name:

`String methodName = "get" + str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.toLowerCase(str)`.

Then it calls `getMethod(methodName)`

If this call succeeds it calls it using `method.invoke()`